# I am creating a simple application in which on successful login I want to navigate from login page to start page

Tags: angular

When user opens my application then I want to show the login page and after successful login I want to navigate to the page **start** page **AppComponent** in it I have added the navigation menu **Home**.
Below are the components and html. When I am clicking on login the URL is changing to localhost:4200/start but the view is not changing.

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './log-in/login.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'start', component: AppComponent},
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
     ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [LoginComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

app.cmponent.html

```
<body>
  <app-nav-menu></app-nav-menu>
  <div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</body>
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent {
  username: string;
  password: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  login(): void {
    if (this.username == 'admin' && this.password == 'admin') {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/start');
    } else {
      alert("Invalid credentials");
    }
  }
}
```

login.component.html

```
<body>
  <input placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" required>
  <input placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="password" type="password" name="password" required>
  <button (click)="login()" color="primary">Login</button>

</body>
```

nav-menu.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-menu',
  templateUrl: './nav-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-menu.component.css']
})
export class NavMenuComponent {
  isExpanded = false;

  collapse() {
    this.isExpanded = false;
  }

  toggle() {
    this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded;
  }
}
```

nav-menu.component.html

```
<header>
  <nav class='navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3'>
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]='["/"]'>SAWindowsAuthentication</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        [attr.aria-expanded]="isExpanded" (click)="toggle()">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse" [ngClass]='{"show": isExpanded}'>
        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow">
          <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]='["link-active"]' [routerLinkActiveOptions]='{ exact: true }'>
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" [routerLink]='["/home"]'>Home</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @tenkmilan No there is no any error in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The components of the routing are displayed by the `<router-outlet>` template tag.

The problem is in the app that in `app.module.ts` the `LoginComponent` is bootstrapped. The `LoginComponent` does not contain any `<router-outlet>` in its template. That's why when the route is changed the routed component won't be shown. The content of the bootstrapped `LoginComponent` remains.

To fix this following steps are needed:

In `app.module.ts` the `AppComponent` has to be bootstrapped because it contains the `<router-outlet>`. The routes should be updated, the route with an empty string should be bound to the `LoginComponent`.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: LoginComponent},
      { path: 'start', component: HomeComponent}
     ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The `AppComponent` should contain the selector for the app root:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

And it should work. In my description I left out the NavMenuComponent because it was not relevant for the question.

You can find the whole solution on StackBlitz here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j5w6sr

Comment: You are welcome! Could you please accept the answer?

Comment: Sure. Accepted :)